# OpenCV on Windows x64 error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, pip, windows-10

I've followed numerous guides and this is where I ended up. I am running Windows 10 x64 and have installed Python 3.6.1 for 64-bit.

I'd like to start using OpenCV with Sublime Text Editor 2, but I am getting an error when trying to install OpenCV via the command prompt. I followed this guide:

https://solarianprogrammer.com/2016/09/17/install-opencv-3-with-python-3-on-windows/

The error is:

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv_python-3.2.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for opencv_python-3.2.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64`

Any ideas? If I've left out any info, feel free to ask and I can tell you. Thanks.

Comment: You haven't told the step that triggered to return the error!

Comment: Maybe you forgot to include the file extension (`.whl`) in the filename? Pip wants the full file name `opencv_python-3.2.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

Answer (score 0):

You have to download opencv_python‑3.2.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and run

```
pip install opencv_python‑3.2.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: Please see the guide I followed. That guide told me to do exactly this, but it returned the error in my question.

Comment: Did you run the command with the file in the current directory? Did you run it exactly, with extension '.whl'? If yes: please show the results of the commands `python --version` and `python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"`.